# Do the words "en dash" and "em dash" require a hyphen?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, compounds, dashes, em-dashes

I have seen the compound words "en dash" and "em dash" sometimes appear with a hyphen ("en-dash") and sometimes without. Are both the hyphenated and the unhyphenated forms correct?

Comment: No. These are defined without a hyphen. They are themselves dashes similar to the hyphen. Some may still hyphenate them, though.

Comment: It depends upon your sense of irony ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no unanimity on the proper form of this term—at least not among U.S. authorities.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) doesn't include entries for the two terms at all, but MW's *Third New International Dictionary* (1986) has "em dash" and "en dash." *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010) shares the *Third New International*'s preference for the no-hyphen style.

But Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003) opts for "em-dash" and "en-dash" throughout his widely respected usage guide.

Perhaps the strangest preference is the one given in *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010), which recommends "emdash" and "endash" but also accepts "em dash" and "en dash."

*Words into Type*, third edition (1974) which uses the open style "em dash" and "en dash," has interesting glossary entries for *em* and *en*:

> **em** In printing, a unit of measurement equal to the space occupied by letter *M* in the given font.
>
> ...
>
> **en** In printing, a unit of measurement equal to half an em.

Why choose the letter *M* as the reference unit of measurement? Elsewhere, *Words into Type* explains:

> **The em.** Another unit of measurement in printing is the em, which is the square of the body size of the type. The name originated from the fact that the body of a letter M in a normal face is the same number of points wide that it is high. The amount of type in a piece of composed matter is measured by ems of the size of type in which it is set; the work of compositors is measured by the number of ems they set.

So *em* was the original term, leading to such subsequent terms as *em space*, *em dash*, and what *Words into Type* styles as *2-em dash*. It seems clear that *M*, *M space*, *M dash*, and *2-M dash* would have made as much sense, logically speaking, as the spelled-out *em* versions of these terms; but the potential for misunderstanding by writers, editors, and typesetters of the intended meaning of a random reference to an *M* undoubtedly pushed the industry toward the spelling *em* for the unit of measurement. I have seen few instances over the years of the hyphenated forms "M-dash," "N-dash," "m-dash," or "n-dash" and even fewer of the open forms "M dash," "N dash," "m dash," and "n dash."

The use of *en* as a term meaning "half an em" is obviously not based on actual measurement of the width of a typical *N* in a typical font in comparison to the width of a typical *M* in that same font; nor is a lowercase *n* half the width of a lowercase *m* in any font that I am aware of. The usage may have arisen simply from the similarity in shape of an *n* to half of an *m*. Typesetters are funny that way, which may also explain why "casting off" was another standard term in pre-computer-era publishing, despite having nothing to do with unmooring a boat.

In any event, the relevant spellings of longest standing and greatest etymological sense are "em dash" and "en dash"; but if you prefer to go to battle with "em-dash" and "en-dash," Bryan Garner is a pretty good ally to share a foxhole with. And if for some reason the weirdly verblike squished-together look of "emdash" and "endash" appeal to you, *The American Heritage Dictionary* is at your service.